# R tabulizer package list of matrices dimensions vary for same format PDF tables

Tags: r, pdf, tabula, tabulizer

I'm using Tabulizer 0.2.2 extract_tables on the following pdf in R on Mac.

sales <- "http://www.greenwichct.org/upload/medialibrary/5cd/Residential-Sales-by-Address-10-10-to-10-15.pdf"

test <- extract_tables(sales,pages=c(1:10),method="decide")

I believe the tables on each page are the same, but resulting list of matrices for the first ten pages for example gives matrices with 3 different dimensions. Columns are sometimes concatenated, for example in test[[3]] with columns 1 and 2.

I have tried setting the area, specifying methods. I have looked around for how to specify the column parameter, but cannot find anything specific. Even went through with extract_area(), but same result. Same problems using Tabula app also.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: The link to the PDF is not valid anymore. Could you provide a link to a new PDF?

Comment: This was a messy pdf 4 years ago, if it is gone, there hopefully never be another one like it. If you are trying to learn how to use tabulizer, there must be better options.

Comment: I am not trying to learn how to use tabulizer. I was just checking if I could help to answer your question ;)